# Vim append date to end of line

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a Vim command to append the date to the end of line. Right now I have the following, and it is not working.

```
nnoremap <F5> "=strftime("%c")<CR>A
```

What's wrong with this? It just throws me back into insert mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"=strftime("%c")<CR>A
```

means "put the date in the expression register then enter insert mode at the end of the line".

Here is what you wanted to do:

```
nnoremap <F5> A<C-r>=strftime("%c")<CR>
```

"enter insert mode at the end of the line and use the expression register to insert the date".

Here is another method, I'm sure there are others:

```
nnoremap <F5> :call setline(".", getline(".") . strftime("%c"))<CR>
```